# Human identifier associated with a wallet

Tags: identity, know-your-customer

I know that, *strong anonymity* is one of the important aspects of Bitcoin; however, the mandate for us is clear. For audit purposes, we need to be able to prove that, the buyer's name in the web form exactly matches with the name associated with the payment instrument. When paying with BTC, it means, every address used to make a payment should be co-related with an human identifier e.g. name, passport number, etc.

Is there a wallet provider who exposes an API responding with a simple `true` or a `false` when the wallet identifier, address and human identifiers are passed as input?

Comment: *"the mandate for us is clear. For audit purposes, we need to be able to prove that, the buyer's name in the web form exactly matches with the name associated with the payment instrument."* If this is the case, then BitCoin is not an appropriate instrument for your transaction.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that the "mandate is clear for us", who is 'us'?

Bitcoin isn't designed to provide full auditable clarity on individuals using/spending it. It has pseudonimity. See conversation in link below.

https://english.stackexchange.com/q/224254

Answer (score 1):

The way you track payments is to hand out unique addresses to each customer. This way you know who to attribute payments to. However the customer could always ask someone else to pay to your address. There is no way to be sure that he made the payment himself.

And BTW I mean your addresses not the buyer's. You never ever track payments based on the sending address.